# I'm curious about installing Windows XP after installing Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, laptop, windows-xp

So, I installed and have been using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS for a bout a year and a half now, and I am quite happy with it.  My only problem is that a lot of games are not supported.  I would use WINE for all of them that I could, but my laptop SUCKS, and it would crash if I did use WINE for most of the games I want to play.  (Yes, I have looked into PlayOnLinux, but to no more success than with WINE.)
   Anyways, I wanted to install Windows XP after already having installed Ubuntu.  Would it just wipe Ubuntu to make space for itself?  I'd be fine with installing Ubuntu again.  I do understand that I could just experiment with it myself, but I don't want to risk screwing up my first laptop just yet.

Thanks for your time!

-------------------Devon

-EDIT-  I've decided to wipe Ubuntu from my laptop and install Windows XP through my Dad's Windows XP discuss and key, then install Ubuntu and go from there.  Thanks for your suggestions, though.

Comment: I meant disk, not discuss.

Answer (score 2):

If you've already installed ubuntu on your computer when you install xp on a (empty) partition you'll need to restore your grub (with an added boot line for xp).

To do this you'll need to create an empty partition where you want to install xp (since you do not want xp to install on top of you linux system, effectively wiping it). You can do this with [partition magic](https://partedmagic.com/). You can also do this with your program of choice but I just like partition magic because it's easy to use and quite save (you should still backup any data that cannot be lost just to be save). Please do keep in mind that if you re-size an partition with data that you do not make it smaller that the amount of data that's on the partition.

Next you'll need to install xp onto this partition which shouldn't be to hard to do. Just make sure you select your partition of choice at the pre-install settings.

After you've done that we're going to restore your grub since you can only boot xp at the moment.
burn a [boot-repair cd](http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/) and boot it. Select "recommended repair" and wait for about a minute til it's done.

Reboot your pc. It should automatically boot into linux but you can select to boot your xp install. To customize your grub menu or change the choice delay you'll need [grub customizer](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer).

This approach always worked for me.

Comment: Wait, so if I do install XP over Ubuntu, Ubuntu will b ed

Comment: *be deleted, correct?

Comment: if you install xp on a partition used by your Ubuntu OS it will be wiped.

Answer (score 0):

I consider installing Windows XP in a virtual machine the best option. The only drawback is performance. But if you have a new lapttop and want to run just simple games, I think that is it!

In Ubuntu, the command to install is

apt-get install virtualbox

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but performance is kind of a must for me.