# Have dual XP and Ubuntu. Want to uninstal and the reinstal XP and keep Ububtu

Tags: uninstall, windows-xp, reinstall

I have both systems right now. I have installed Ubuntu from CD. My XP is divided in two parts (system and local disc).
I would like to uninstall XP and install it again fresh. 
There is no option to uninstall XP at Add/Remove Programs.

How can I do that with keeping my local disc intact?

Thank you very much! :)

Nikoleta

Comment: What is your need? You'd like to install XP and Ubuntu or XP alone? Could you clarify it?

Comment: Does this post help you? http://askubuntu.com/questions/383115/im-curious-about-installing-windows-xp-after-installing-ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

1. Boot from your XP disc
2. Install it normally into exactly the same disk partition as it was before.
3. Installator will ask you if to format patition. Do it.
4. Boot from your Ubuntu disk.
5. Restore the bootloader. [Like this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145241/how-do-i-run-update-grub-from-a-livecd/)

You can see the layout of your disk partitions with `lsblk` console command or Gparted application.